# Tablesorter - Dates Problem

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I know there have been some questions about this, but I can't seem to fix my problem.

I'm loading a .csv file into tablesorter, but one of my columns are dates (Dec 23, 2009). But they sort as Dec 2, Dec 23, Dec 3, Dec 31

Does anyone know a solution? [You can see the problem here](http://www.caesarsreport.com/PortCanada), it's the table at the bottom. Thanks so much in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() 
      { 
          $("#tablesorter-demo2").tablesorter({ widgets: ['zebra'] });
      } 
  );
 </script>
```

-

> table width="871" border="0"
>   cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1"
>   class="tablesorter"
>   id="tablesorter-demo">
>
> ```
> $row = 1;
> $handle = fopen("csv/canadatransactions.csv",
> ```
>
> "r");
>       while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
>       {
>           $num = count($data);
>           $row++;
>
> ```
>                 if ($row == 2)
>                {
>                    echo "<thead>\n<tr>\n";
>
>                    echo "<th class=\"header\">" . $data[1] .
> ```
>
> "\n"; // name
>           echo "" . $data[0] . "\n"; // symbol
>                          echo "" . $data[2] .
>   "\n"; // buy sell
>                          echo "" . $data[3] .
>   "\n"; // date
>                          echo "" . $data[4] .
>   "\n"; // shares
>           echo "" . $data[5] . "\n"; // price
>         echo "" . $data[6] . "\n"; // cash value
>
> ```
>                    echo "</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>";
>                }
>
>                else
>                {
>                    echo "<tr class=\"even\"";
>                    echo ">\n";
>                    echo "<td>" . $data[1] . "</td>\n";
>     echo "<td>" . $data[0] . "</td>\n";
>     echo "<td>" . $data[2] . "</td>\n";
>     echo "<td>" . $data[3] . "</td>\n";
>     echo "<td>" . $data[4] . "</td>\n";
>     echo "<td>C$ " . $data[5] . "</td>\n";
>     echo "<td>C$ " . $data[6] . "</td>\n";
>
>                    $transactions = $row - 3;
>  }
> }
> fclose($handle);
> ?>
>             </tbody>
> </table>
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's sorting based on alphanumeric (ASCII) values, not based on date-values (It will also put November before October).  You need jquery to interpret each cell as a date value and then sort them accordingly.  If their built-in type detection isn't working, you have to force the data type.  See http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/09/29/jquery-tablesorter-list-of-builtin-parserssorters/ for more information.

Comment: Works great. I love the fact I have manual control over the columns. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the type of the column. Otherwise it will be sorted as text. You can do it by specyfing `sorter` parameter:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        ... other columns ....
        <th class="{sorter: 'isoDate'}">Date</th>
</tr>           
</thead>
<tbody>
... table body ....
```

Alhough I'm not sure if `isoDate` is the sorter you should use, but tablesorter have two other sorters: `usLongDate` and `shortDate`. You can try which one of those will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the default date sorting options work, try using a [custom parser](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html) and converting the date to it's equivalent millisecond representation for sorting.

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'dateMS', 
    is: function(s) { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        var d = Date.parse(s);
        if (isNaN(d)) {
           return -1;
        }
        return d;
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric' 
});     

$(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            6: { 
                sorter:'dateMS' 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But disabling the internal auto-detect from tablesorter does the trick also. He was reading my data as text.